# when selecting input leave only it as an available option

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input with ngfor, it appears several options

```
<article *ngIf="layout=='esalpet'" class="filter-group">
<header class="card-header">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_4" aria-expanded="true" class="">
        <i class="icon-control fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <h6 class="title">Marcas</h6>
    </a>
</header>
<div class="filter-content collapse show" id="collapse_4">
    <div *ngFor="let categ of filtro" class="card-body">
        <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input (change)="filterMarcas($event)" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="5" name="marca"
                value="{{categ.marcaJ.marca}}" id="flexCheckChecked" />

            <div class="custom-control-label" id="5">{{categ.marcaJ.marca}}</div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <!-- card-body.// -->
</div>
```

when selecting some of the inputs, I would like only the input selected by the user to appear

follow my method i tried to do

```
filterMarcas(event){
this.slicedItems = this.slicedItems.filter(item => item.marcaJ?.marca === event.target.value  )
console.log(this.slicedItems)
this.filtro = this.slicedItems.filter((record, index) => this.filtro.findIndex(check => check.marcaJ?.marca === record.marcaJ?.marca) === index);
this.peso = this.peso.filter((record, index) => this.peso.findIndex(check => check.peso === record.peso) === index);


}
```

Is there a better method than this?

```
    this.filtro = this.slicedItems.filter((record, index) => this.filtro.findIndex(check => check.marcaJ?.marca === record.marcaJ?.marca) === index);
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `PipeTransform`

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

interface Marca {
  marcaJ: {
    marca: string
  }
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'marcaFilter'
})
export class MarcaFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(marcas: Marca[], name: string): Marca[] {
    if (!name) {
      return marcas;
    }
    return marcas.filter(marca => marca.marcaJ?.marca === name);
  }
}
```

Declare it within your module.

```js
@NgModule({
  ...,
  declarations: [
    ...
    MarcaFilterPipe,
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And add the pipe to your `*ngFor`

```html
<div *ngFor="let categ of filtro | marcaFilter: categ.marcaJ.marca">
...
</div>
```